# Validad textarea con máximo de caracteres, javascript

Tags: javascript, input, textarea

Quiero limitar el número de caracteres que haya en un **textarea**. Ahora bien, no me vale usar el atributo de HTML *maxlength="numero"*, tengo que hacerlo mediante **javascript** y que cuando acabes de escribir y salgas del textarea te informe, en caso de que te hayas excedido, de que has superado el número de caracteres, pero que te deje continuar rellenando el resto de input que tenga el formulario. Quiero validar el textarea. El formulario no podrá enviarse hasta que no este validado el textarea, que a su vez debe contener información y no puede estar en blanco.

Adjunto el código con el que estoy empezando:

**HTML**

```
<form id="formulario">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Datos para enviar</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="nombre">Introduce tu nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="escribe tu nombre" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="email">Introduce tu email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="escribe tu email" required>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="message">Introduce el mensaje que desees:</label>
                <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" maxlength="50" required></textarea>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <button id="inputsubmit" type="submit" class="formsubmit">Enviar</button>

        <button id="inputreset" type="reset" class="formreset">Borrar datos</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

¿Qué código podría añadirle en javascript para esto?

He encontrado algo de código, pero no lo hago funcionar.

JavaScript

```
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("message").maxLength = "100";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Maximum number of characters allowed in the text area is now 100.";
}
```

Como he dicho me gustaría que el mensaje se observara cuando sales del **textarea**, sin que sea un **alert**, que permita continuar rellenando otros input, pero que si intentas enviar el formulario, no lo haga y vuelva a salir el mensaje de error por superar el número máximo de caracteres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con JS Vanilla o en mi caso personal, lo haría utilizando JQuery y Bootstrap.

Quedaría algo, tal que así:

**Importaciones**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**HTML**

```html
<textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" 
  aria-label="With textarea" maxlength="128"></textarea>
<span class="help-block">
  <p id="mensaje_ayuda" class="help-block">Cuerpo del mensaje de alerta</p>
</span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inputsubmit" 
  name="inputsubmit"><i data-feather="check"></i>&nbsp;Enviar</button>
```

**JQuery**

```
  $('#mensaje_ayuda').text('20 carácteres restantes');
  $('#message').keydown(function () {
      var max = 20;
      var len = $(this).val().length;
      if (len >= max) {
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').text('Has llegado al límite');// Aquí enviamos el mensaje a mostrar          
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').addClass('text-danger');
          $('#message').addClass('is-invalid');
          $('#inputsubmit').addClass('disabled');    
          document.getElementById('inputsubmit').disabled = true;                    
      } 
      else {
          var ch = max - len;
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').text(ch + ' carácteres restantes');
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').removeClass('text-danger');            
          $('#message').removeClass('is-invalid');            
          $('#inputsubmit').removeClass('disabled');
          document.getElementById('inputsubmit').disabled = false;            
      }
  });
```

Cabe aclarar que la validación la hago con explicitamente con JQuery y Bootstrap lo utilizo para darle estilos al mensaje de aviso, textarea y al botón, cuando la validación determina que se ha alcanzado el límite de caracteres.
Puedes probarlo ejecutando el siguiente código. Espero te sea útil

```js
$('#mensaje_ayuda').text('20 carácteres restantes');
  $('#message').keydown(function () {
      var max = 20;
      var len = $(this).val().length;
      if (len >= max) {
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').text('Has llegado al límite');// Aquí enviamos el mensaje a mostrar          
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').addClass('text-danger');
          $('#message').addClass('is-invalid');
          $('#inputsubmit').addClass('disabled');    
          document.getElementById('inputsubmit').disabled = true;                    
      } 
      else {
          var ch = max - len;
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').text(ch + ' carácteres restantes');
          $('#mensaje_ayuda').removeClass('text-danger');            
          $('#message').removeClass('is-invalid');            
          $('#inputsubmit').removeClass('disabled');
          document.getElementById('inputsubmit').disabled = false;            
      }
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control" 
  aria-label="With textarea" maxlength="20"></textarea>
<span class="help-block">
  <p id="mensaje_ayuda" class="help-block">Cuerpo del mensaje de alerta</p>
</span>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="inputsubmit" 
  name="inputsubmit"><i data-feather="check"></i>&nbsp;Enviar</button>
```

Comment: ¿En qué parte del proceso de tu validación interactúa bootstrap?

Comment: La validación "per se" la hago con JQuery. Bootstrap lo utilizo para dar estilo al mensaje de aviso, el text area y al botón, cuando la validación de JQuery determina que se ha alcanzado el límite de caracteres.

Comment: Ok, considera explicarle eso al OP en tu respuesta, ya que es confusa y suena a que es necesario bootstrap para validar, cuando de hecho es solo para estilizar

Comment: Entendido, ahorita mismo hago la aclaración. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías capturar cada uno de los caracteres que se ingresan al *textarea*, de modo que puedas contar cuántos caracteres tiene y de ese modo *setear* una variable de control.

```js
const maxPermitted = 10;
// La varible de control
let validArea = true;

const area = document.querySelector('#area');
const submit = document.querySelector('#sbmit');
const error = document.querySelector('#area-error');

submit.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    // Quizás sería más conveniente darle el
    // atributo 'disabled' true/false
    // en los métodos 'handleValid' y
    // 'handleInvalid'
    if (validArea)
        console.log(`valid`);
    else
        console.warn(`invalid`)
})

// Nos suscribimos al evento 'input'
// del area, que se disparará cada
// vez que cambie el valor del textarea
area.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
    const { value } = area;
    
    value.length >= maxPermitted
        ? handleInvalid()
        : handleValid();
});

// Mostramos el texto de error
const handleInvalid = () => {
    validArea = false;
    error.style.display = `block`;
}

// Ocultamos el bloque de error
const handleValid = () => {
    validArea = true;
    error.style.display = `none`;
}
```

```css
.txt-area {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#area {
    width: 50%;
}

.error {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: rgb(221, 2, 2);
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="txt-area">
    <textarea id="area"></textarea>
    <div class="error" id="area-error">Characters overflow</div>
</div>

<button id="sbmit">Submit</button>
```

Se podría hacer de muchas otras formas y mejores. Pero para que tengas una idea, creo que puede servir esta. Lo importante es suscribirte al evento `input` y de ahí ejecutar la lógica que te convenga.

Espero que sirva.

Answer (score 0):

**De esta forma te puede servir:**

- Necesitarías ejecutar una función de validación cada vez que el **textarea** ejecute el evento **onBlur** que seria en el mismo instante que el **textarea** pierde el foco
- Debes crear un contendor en **HTML** para que se muestre el mensaje de error correspondiente.
- Por default deshabilitas el **submit**
- El **submit** solo se habilitara si se cumples las validaciones correspondientes

```js
// variables
var error = document.getElementById('error');
var message = document.getElementById('message');
var inputsubmit = document.getElementById('inputsubmit');

/**
* Valida el formulario y muestra un mensaje
* sino se cumple lo siguiente:
* - El Mensaje no puede estar vacio
* - El mensaje no puede ser mayor que 100 caracteres
*/
function isValidForm() {
  var value = message.value;
  
  if(!value){
    error.innerHTML = "El mensaje es requerido."
  } else if(value.length > 100){
    error.innerHTML = "El mensaje no debe exceder los 100 caracteres";
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = "";
  }

  if(error.innerHTML){
    inputsubmit.setAttribute("disabled", true);
  } else {
    inputsubmit.removeAttribute("disabled")
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Datos para enviar</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label for="nombre">Introduce tu nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="" placeholder="escribe tu nombre" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="email">Introduce tu email</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="escribe tu email" required>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="message">Introduce el mensaje que desees:</label>
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Escribe tu mensaje" required onBlur="isValidForm()"></textarea>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button id="inputsubmit" type="submit" class="formsubmit" disabled>Enviar</button>

    <button id="inputreset" type="reset" class="formreset">Borrar datos</button>

  </fieldset>
  <div id="error"></div>
</form>
```